# ubuntu xfce4 эмуляция нажатия средней кнопки мыши на тачпаде

Tags: ubuntu, xfce4

У меян был ноутбук lenovo v580. У меня там стояла ubuntu c xfce4. Я выделял текст и затем вставлял его одновременным нажатием на правую и левую кнопки тачпада.

Затем я купил новый ноут asus rog gl752vw, поставил на него ту же систему ubuntu 18.10 и xfce4. На этом буке одновременное нажатие на правую и левую кнопки тачпада не работают так как работали на старом.

Помогите советом, как решить данную проблему.
Спасибо

Comment: приложите к вопросу (нажав [edit]) вывод команды `$ xinput --list-props "$(xinput list --name-only | grep -i touchpad | head -n 1)"`

Comment: и ещё: нажатие отдельно на левую кнопку какой эффект имеет? а нажатие отдельно на правую?

Comment: если предложенная выше команда вернёт ошибку (что-нибудь вроде "unable to find device"), приложите вывод `$ xinput --list; xinput --list-props 11`